# Firebase admin: list all users returns empty array

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have an https-callable firebase cloud function to return all users as an array of their userRecords. I push each of the userRecords into an array which I later return, but it returns an empty array.

How can I return this array to the client?

**index.js:**

```
exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // List all users

  return listAllUsers();
});

function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  var allUsers = [];

  return admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function (listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
        // For each user
        var userData = userRecord.toJSON();
        allUsers.push(userData);
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        console.log('Next batch of users');

        return listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken)
      }
      else {
        // All users have been fetched
        console.log('All users have been fetched');

        return allUsers
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });

}
```

**Client side**

```
const listAllUsers = this.afFunctions.httpsCallable('listAllUsers');
    listAllUsers({}).toPromise()
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

[image: Empty array is returned]

Comment: I think the way your code is written, it will always return the last page of the users. And the last page always happens to be empty in this API, so you end up receiving an empty array. You need to keep passing the `allUsers` array to subsequent recursive calls, so all users will accumulate in the array.

Comment: But please note that this is not going to scale if you have a large number of users in the project. It's going to be slow, consume a lot of memory, and network bandwidth to send all that data over the wire.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer @HiranyaJayathilaka! What is a scalable way of doing it?

Comment: Implement paging, similar to how the `auth.listUsers()` method is paged.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a shot in the dark, but for me it was the fact that I had [`FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks) set. Once I commented it out, and restarted my IDE, it started working again.

Whatever your scenario, best is probably to look at your `initializeApp` function and to verify what goes into it, plus ensure the emulator (and the env variable for the auth host - as mentioned above) is off while you're running the script.